# Some people eat Sehri until they hear Fairj adhan, Is this acceptable?

Tags: sunnah, sawm

Consider that sehri time is before 4.30 AM and Fajr time is around 5.30 AM.

But, some of my friends and relatives do sehri after 4.30 AM and they try to complete it before the call to prayer(Adhan) for Fajr - 5.30 AM.

If it is wrong, are there any hadiths or sayings from Quran stating it is wrong ?

Also, they are saying that, it can be done and I'm confused. Then, what is the necessity of following the time, where everyone can follow the Adhan?

Answer (score 1):

The prophet PBUH said:

> قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ : ( إِذَا سَمِعَ أَحَدُكُمْ النِّدَاءَ وَالإِنَاءُ عَلَى يَدِهِ فَلا يَضَعْهُ حَتَّى يَقْضِيَ حَاجَتَهُ مِنْهُ ) رواه أحمد (10251) وأبو داود (2350) وصححه الألباني في صحيح أبي داود
>
> If someone hears the Athan and in there is a plate in his hand, do not leave the plate until you are done with it.

There are 2 views to this hadith. Many scholars went with the reasoning that Bilal used to make Athan before the Fajir time and then again After Fajir time, according to the following hadith:

> ( إِنَّ بِلالا يُؤَذِّنُ بِلَيْلٍ ، فَكُلُوا وَاشْرَبُوا حَتَّى يُؤَذِّنَ ابْنُ أُمِّ مَكْتُومٍ ) رواه البخاري ومسلم
>
> Bilal used to make athan at night, eat and drink until son of Um Maktoom makes athan.

The Majority of scholars went with the timing according to the Quranic Ayah and that if you know the Athan happens after that you have to stop if before you can continue to finish. Umar ben Alkahtab used to say:

> أن عمر بن الخطاب كان يقول : إذا شك الرجلان في الفجر فليأكلا حتى يستيقنا
>
> If two people are in doubt if the Fajir time came or not, they should eat until they are certain of the time.

Here is the source + full explanation in Arabic if you want:

http://islamqa.info/ar/66202

Answer (score 0):

i think they misunderstood the "sahar" time and they think it as time to start eating.

really it is probably time of end of eating and fajr prayer can be done after that time before "fajr" time.

and probably the "fajr" time means time used in that country to read prayers in mosques, and it is set to different time from "sahar" time because in months except ramadan sahar time is not used and only fajr time is used and they set fajr time to later time because they (country's registered religious organisation) think true beginning of fajr time is too early; or, maybe, they set fajr time to time which is easy to calculate for example sunrise time - 2 hours and it falls into fajr time in that seazon/period of year in that country.

Answer (score -1):

doing sehri after subh Sadiq breaks the fast, the Fajr Adhan is given after Subh Sadiq, if someone eats after Subh Sadiq his fast will break.

Comment: "Fajr Adhan is given after Subh Sadiq" I think that depends on the country. In some countries there are two adhans...one before and one after.